# Error after configuring Ametys CMS and restaring it with new configuration (Java, Tomcat, XAMPP)

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

After I had deployed succesfully the Ametys CMS to my Tomcat server (XAMPP), I accessed the configuration link `http://localhost/cms` and started completing the necessary data. The I click Save and restart and it shows an error:

An error occurred. Please contact the administrator of the application.

here are the details it is showing:

`An error occurred. Please contact the administrator of the application.org.apache.avalon.framework.component.ComponentException: Unable to initialize the ComponentManager (key [org.apache.cocoon.Processor]) at org.ametys.runtime.cocoon.TreeProcessor.compose(TreeProcessor.java:94) at org.apache.avalon.framework.container.ContainerUtil.compose(ContainerUtil.java:173) at org.apache.avalon.excalibur.component.DefaultComponentFactory.newInstance(DefaultComponentFactory.java:266) at org.apache.avalon.excalibur.component.ThreadSafeComponentHandler.initialize(ThreadSafeComponentHandler.java:108) at org.apache.avalon.excalibur.component.ExcaliburComponentManager.initialize(ExcaliburComponentManager.java:524) at org.apache.cocoon.components.CocoonComponentManager.initialize(CocoonComponentManager.java:583) at org.apache.avalon.framework.container.ContainerUtil.initialize(ContainerUtil.java:244) at org.apache.cocoon.Cocoon.initialize(Cocoon.java:345) at org.apache.avalon.framework.container.ContainerUtil.initialize(ContainerUtil.java:244) at org.apache.cocoon.servlet.CocoonServlet.createCocoon(CocoonServlet.java:1435) at org.ametys.runtime.servlet.RuntimeServlet.createCocoon(RuntimeServlet.java:225) at org.apache.cocoon.servlet.CocoonServlet.init(CocoonServlet.java:495) at org.ametys.runtime.servlet.RuntimeServlet.init(RuntimeServlet.java:171) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460) at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633) at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1113) at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1671) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by: org.apache.avalon.framework.configuration.ConfigurationException: Specified driver class does not exist: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver at org.ametys.runtime.datasource.DataSourceExtensionPoint.addExtension(DataSourceExtensionPoint.java:65) at org.ametys.runtime.plugin.PluginsManager._loadExtensions(PluginsManager.java:1077) at org.ametys.runtime.plugin.PluginsManager._loadFeatures(PluginsManager.java:1030) at org.ametys.runtime.plugin.PluginsManager.initExtensions(PluginsManager.java:472) at org.ametys.runtime.cocoon.TreeProcessor.compose(TreeProcessor.java:65) ... 29 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714) at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559) at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186) at org.ametys.runtime.datasource.DataSourceExtensionPoint.addExtension(DataSourceExtensionPoint.java:61) ... 33 more`

Does anyone know what is all about? Tried googling, haven't find anything helpful, like restarting the Tomcat.
I know Java for desktop, mobile, but I don't know much of deploying webapps with Tomcat. I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was that the Tomcat was missing the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar` library. I have placed it in tomcat/lib/, the error is gone. Next time I should look more carefully in the log.